# two dimensional array in a UML diagram

Tags: java, arrays, uml, diagram

Whenever i try to display a two dimensional array object in a diagram using NClass for example it keeps giving me an error saying its invalid declaration, however it doesn't give any error using a 1 dimensional array. Any tips would be appreciated
I have posted a screenshot of the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAiyp.png)

Comment: So you're drawing a UML diagram and you got an error. Beside the side issue that you have forgotten to tell us what application you've used, how is that related to Java programming?

Comment: i stated that i used NClass app

Answer (score 0):

It's so difficult to discover what the tool is used in your question. In any way, the same tools support the object description, relations etc. From your screen, I can guess, that your soft don't support java format of description like: "`int[][] board`" and attribute "`protected`". I can guess that you need to write only "`int[][] board`" or only "`board`" and in its description `int[][]`, but attribute "`protected`" you need to write in another place.

Comment: i used the NClass application

Comment: You can see here a tutorial, maybe it can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25sKJgprAlk